# How do I replace the Python Build-in method, with a 3rd party installed module instead?

Tags: python, pbkdf2

I am optimizing my code and replaced the Python build-in hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac with the 40% faster [Fast PBKDF2](https://github.com/ctz/fastpbkdf2) implementation [python-fastpbkdf2](https://github.com/Ayrx/python-fastpbkdf2).

However using cProfile the outcome seems the same.

I have (tried) to make sure I use the Fast PBKDF2 module instead of the build-in hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac module but I can't seem to find out why I don't see the 40% performance increase.

```
from fastpbkdf2 import pbkdf2_hmac

phrase_words = "clerk great coin mistake become"
passphrase = 'passphrase'

seed = pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', bytes(complete_phrase_words, encoding='utf-8'), bytes('mnemonic' + passphrase, encoding='utf-8'), 2048)
```

How do I make sure I do not use the build in method?

cProfile report:

```
186811385 function calls (186811349 primitive calls) in 885.041 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   109344  710.505    0.006  710.505    0.006 {built-in method _fastpbkdf2.fastpbkdf2_hmac_sha512}
 57919431   54.060    0.000   54.060    0.000 {built-in method builtins.format}
 57918564   45.288    0.000  116.547    0.000 crypto_awesomer_fast_pbkdf2_test.py:75(<genexpr>)
  3619696   20.854    0.000  137.401    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
 57919431   20.604    0.000   20.604    0.000 {method 'zfill' of 'str' objects}
  1755108   14.666    0.000  877.752    0.001 crypto_awesomer_fast_pbkdf2_test.py:66(validate)
  1755108    4.119    0.000    4.119    0.000 {method 'to_bytes' of 'int' objects}
  1755108    3.949    0.000    3.949    0.000 {method 'digest' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
        1    3.825    3.825  884.982  884.982 crypto_awesomer_fast_pbkdf2_test.py:33(nested_loops)
  1755109    2.859    0.000    2.859    0.000 {built-in method _hashlib.openssl_sha256}
   109344    1.937    0.000  714.213    0.007 crypto_awesomer_fast_pbkdf2_test.py:89(generate_seed)
   109344    1.315    0.000  712.156    0.007 __init__.py:18(pbkdf2_hmac)
```

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed? Python uses a fast implementation provided by OpenSSL if it is available instead of the built-in one, maybe that is why you see no speed difference. It seems python-fastpbkdf2 hasn't been updated in years, I would take their benchmarks with a grain of salt.

Comment: Yes indeed. Without OpenSSL the Fast PBKDF2 module gave me the 'fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found' which I solved by installing OpenSSL using 'brew install openssl' and 'brew link --force openssl'.

Answer (score 3):

You did use the Fast PBKDF2 module, as the `cProfile` output shows.

I'm guessing whatever performance measurements made by `python-fastpbkdf2` were comparing against older versions of Python, OpenSSL, or both, and newer versions caught up on speed (while Fast PBKDF2 hasn't seen an update in over three years). As it happens, it looks like as of 2016 (a year after Fast PBKDF2 saw its last update), [Python added a fast path when linked against OpenSSL 1.1.0 or higher that uses OpenSSL's optimized `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/598894ff48e9c1171cb2ec1c798235826a75c7e0) rather than Python's homegrown (slower) version. And even before that, [Python had improved their homegrown version back in late 2013](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e723622775172a2516f43721d998aae95f32e59d); if the `python-fastpbkdf2` benchmarks were run before that improvement was released, the performance would have been much worse.

Basically, don't assume claims of being 40% faster are true, even if they were true in the past (and there's no guarantee they were true in the past either).

It's also possible compilers and/or your package repo maintainers built better versions of OpenSSL; at least one of the claimed benefits of Fast PBKDF2 is that he explicitly inlined a number of operations, but a properly compiled version of OpenSSL using PGO+LTO would be able to automatically inline the appropriate operations anyway (and if the setup files for `python-fastpbkdf2` didn't properly build it with PGO+LTO, it could lose out as a result). Between that and OpenSSL making similar code improvements, the gap could easily have narrowed.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Is there a way to confirm if the version of OpenSSL I use is a properly compiled version of OpenSSL using PGO+LTO?

Comment: How to confirm if Python build-in hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac is using the installed OpenSSL?

Comment: @rphessing: You can check the OpenSSL version number that Python is linked to with `import ssl` `print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)`; anything 1.1.0 or above will use the fast path. If Python happens to be linked to the system `openssl`, you can check the build flags for `openssl` with `openssl version -f`; on my Ubuntu build, it doesn't look like PGO or LTO were used, but it's wholly possible OpenSSL made the same manual improvements as Fast PBKDF2 in the fast path Python uses as of 1.1.0, so it may not need it.